# how do I paint one of the check when user click mouse on it

Tags: c#, arrays

I have something like chessboard, 21x21 checks, each of one have 10x10pixels. I have no idea how do I paint one of the check when user click mouse on it.

Probably i have to use arrays but i dont know how can I assign 10x10 pixels to one element of other array. Can i assign array wiht 100 elements to one elemnet of other array?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace gotowa_mapa
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap mapa;
    private int szer_pb = 200;
    private int wys_pb = 200;
    private int ilosc_kratek_x = 41;
    private int ilosc_kratek_y = 41;


   // private void wpisanie_tablic()
    //{
       // int[,] tablica_kratki = new int[ilosc_kratek_x, ilosc_kratek_y];
       // int[,] tablica_piksele = new int[szer_pb, wys_pb];

        //for(int i=0;i<ilosc_kratek_x; i++)
       // {
           // for(int j=0; j<ilosc_kratek_y; j++)
            //{
               // tablica_kratki[ilosc_kratek_x, ilosc_kratek_y] = tablica_piksele[2,2];

            //}
        //}

    //}
    private void siatka1()
    {
        mapa = new Bitmap(szer_pb, wys_pb);
        int factor_x = (int)(szer_pb / ilosc_kratek_x);
        int factor_y = (int)(wys_pb / ilosc_kratek_y);

        for (int i = 0; i < szer_pb; i++)
        {
            if (i > (factor_x * ilosc_kratek_x))
                break;

            for (int j = 0; j < wys_pb; j++)
            {
                if (j > (factor_y * ilosc_kratek_y))
                    break;

                if (i % (factor_x) == 0 || j % (factor_y) == 0)
                {
                    mapa.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Black);
                    mapa.SetPixel(j, i, Color.Black);
                }
                else
                {
                    mapa.SetPixel(i, j, Color.White);
                    mapa.SetPixel(j, i, Color.White);
                }

            }
        }

    }

   // private void rysowanie_scian(int x, int y)
   // {





   // }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        siatka1();
        pictureBox1.Image = mapa;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        int x, y;
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;

        MessageBox.Show(x + " " + y);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example for you, although there is probably better ways of doing this, using some simple math you can achieve this.

A neat trick is overriding the **onPaint** method of a panel, making a new Bitmap with the same size as the panel, drawing this image over the panel during the onPaint method, making changes directly to the image, then invalidating the panel so it draws the image. (You can then save the image with Bitmap.Save)

Keep in mind, if a game of some sort is what you are aiming for, GDI is not ideal, look into managed DirectX or similar.

```
    //declare variables
    public const int offset = 50;
    public const int boardX = 10;
    public const int boardY = 10;
    public const int checkSize = 40;
    int[] checks;

    //set initial values for the checks array
    if(checks == null)
    {
        checks = new int[boardX * boardY];
    }

    //start iterating through the array of checks
    for (int i = 0; i < checks.Length; i++)
    {
        //if the check is empty (assuming you will use integers as identifiers for the pieces on the board)
        if (checks[i] < 1)
        {
            //check if the check in array is odd number & paint odd numbers black on alternating rows
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                //check if row is odd
                if (Math.Ceiling((double)(i + 1) / boardX) % 2 != 0)
                {
                    drawCheck(Brushes.Black, e.Graphics, i);
                }
                else
                {
                    drawCheck(Brushes.White, e.Graphics, i)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //check if row is odd
                if (Math.Ceiling((double)(i+1) / boardX) % 2 != 0;
                {
                    drawCheck(Brushes.White, e.Graphics, i);
                }
                else
                {
                    drawCheck(Brushes.Black, e.Graphics, i)
                }
            }
        }
        else if (checks[i] == 1)
        {
            //the check is a "clicked check" - draw it red
            drawCheck(Brushes.Red, e.Graphics, i);
        }
    }

    //The Methods
    private void YOURDRAWINGSURFACE_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.X < (boardX * checkSize) + offset && e.Y < (boardY * checkSize) + offset && e.X > offset && e.Y > offset )
        {
            //you have clicked somewhere on the board. if that square isn't red, make it so, else turn it back to a normal square
            if (checks[checkClicked(e.X, e.Y)] != 1)
            {
                checks[checkClicked(e.X, e.Y)] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                checks[checkClicked(e.X, e.Y)] = 0;
            }
        }


        //this is only relevant for GDI drawing code. It will invalidate the form to redraw the surface (needs to be called whenever you make a change)
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    public int checkClicked(int mouseX, int mouseY)
    {
        //this method returns the int of the particular check that was clicked in the array.
        return ((int)Math.Ceiling((double)(mouseX - offset) / checkSize) + (int)((Math.Ceiling((double)(mouseY - offset) / checkSize)) * boardX) - (1 + boardX));
    }

    public void drawCheck(Brush brush, Graphics graphics, int checkNumber)
    {
        //this method draws the check given the parameters.
        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ((checkNumber % boardX) * checkSize) + offset, (int)(Math.Ceiling((double)(checkNumber-(boardX-1)) / boardX) * checkSize) + offset, checkSize, checkSize);
    }
```